# Limit of e^-x and 1/e^x as x goes to infinity.

Tags: calculus

I am pretty sure my understanding may be incorrect so please guide. Wouldn't the limit of e^-x as x goes to infinity simply be e^-infinity? Looking at the graph of e^-x, e^-infinity would be positive infinity, correct? 
But I also know that e^-x is also the same as 1/e^x so in this case plugging in infinity would give me 1/infinity which would just be zero?

Why am I getting two different answers? Please shed some light on limits (without using l'hopitals rule). I thought I was getting the concept of limits until this.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think that $e^{-\infty}$ would be $\infty$?

Comment: Oh dear! I just realized my mistake. I was looking at the negative side of e^-x!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have included the graph of $\exp(-x)$, it converges to $0$. Notice that $e^{-1}$ is a positive number that is less than $1$, hence it converges to $0$.

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! I just realized my error